# $_POST["action"] == "edit"

Tags: php

How can I go to this `if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "edit")  statement`?

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "edit")    {
        //Assemble the the postData
        );
        //Call the RestClient with PUT
        RestClient::call("PUT",$postData);

    }
}
```

When I click the `'edit'` button like this?

```
<h4>Edit Customer - <?php echo $c->getCustomerID(); ?></h4>
    <!-- The above form looks like this -->
    <form method="POST" ACTION="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
        <!-- Would some hidden fields help to route the data?  Probably -->

        <div class="row">

            <div class="six columns">
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input type="text" name="ename" value=<?php echo $c->getName();?>>
            </div>

            <div class="six columns">
            <label for="name">address</label>
            <input type="text" name="eaddress" value=<?php echo $c->getAddress();?>>
            </div>

            <div class="six columns">
            <label for="name">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="ecity" value=<?php echo $c->getCity();?>>
            </div>

        </div>
        <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Edit">

        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to catch your submit button's value, the first thing you have to do is give it a name with the value of "action":

```
<input class="button-primary" name="action" type="submit" value="Edit">
```

And then match your button's value *exactly* (meaning case-sensitive):

```
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] === "Edit")
```

That's how you would do it, although it doesn't make sense unless you're going to have multiple forms where each submit button's name is "action", and doing so is not a good practice. **A much more sensible approach** is just giving the submit a name that reflects the action:

```
<input class="button-primary" name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit">
```

And then simply check if that name is set:

```
if (isset($_POST["edit"]))
```

Also note that `ACTION="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"` is unnecessary, as the default action is to submit to self, so you can just drop the entire attribute.

Comment: It is actually unwise from a security perspective to use `PHP_SELF` here . And +1 for using the correct `===` comparison operator `:-)`

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit"/>
```